# Cannot resolve @androidx.annotation.NonNull , Cannot resolve method anonymous android.hardware.camera2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, annotations, androidx

I'm trying to Open the Camera using Camera.2 API, when I call `openCamera` and pass `CameraDevice.StateCallback` to it I get on each callback 2 `NonNull` one belongs to `androidx.annotation` and the other to `android.support.annotatoin`, both of them are called by default, `androidx.annotation` cannot be resolved, and if I tried to delete it I get `Cannot resolve method openCamera(,anonymous android.hardware.camera2)`

Attaching below the code and pictures from Android Studio for better visualization:

**Before deleting**

[image: First]

**After deleting**

[image: Second]

**Code:**

```
CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);

        cameraManager.openCamera(CAMERA_ID, new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(@androidx.annotation.NonNull @NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(@androidx.annotation.NonNull @NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@androidx.annotation.NonNull @NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: @Kartik Didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very simple problem I just had to pass 3rd argument to `openCamera` with `null` value and remove `@androidx.annotation.NonNull`